# Load select option values from XML file

Tags: php, xml

I would like to find a way to load select option values from a XML file.
For example `<option value="XXXXXX">XXXXXX</option>` where the XXXXXX value is the `<TITLE>XXXXXX</TITLE>` of the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<CATEGORIES> 
  <CD id="1">
    <TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE>
    <BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND>
    <YEAR>1977</YEAR>
  </CD>
  <CD id="2">
    <TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE>
    <BAND>NIRVANA</BAND>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
  </CD>
</CATEGORIES>
```

Comment: what?? please show us an example of the xml structure.

Comment: Hello, this imy XML structure. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <CATEGORIES> <CD id="1"> <TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE> <BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND> <YEAR>1977</YEAR> </CD> <CD id="2"> <TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE> <BAND>NIRVANA</BAND> <YEAR>1991</YEAR> </CD> </CATEGORIES>

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code, it's much easier to read that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(haven't tested this):

```
$optionsXML = simplexml_load_file("OptionsList.xml"); //Replace OptionsList.xml with your file path.
$options =  $optionsXML->xpath("//TITLE/text()");
echo '<select name="test">';
while(list( $key , $value) = each($options)) {
    echo '<option >' . $value . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

EDIT: Updated the post to reflect the XML posted by OP.

Comment: I am having some problem to implement it right. this is my XML structure. Thank you for your help!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATEGORIES>
   
<CD id="1">
<TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE>
<BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND>
<YEAR>1977</YEAR>  
</CD>

<CD id="2">    
<TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE>
<BAND>NIRVANA</BAND>
<YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
</CD>
</CATEGORIES>

Comment: Ok. So what field of XML do you want to display for value and what field for text of the dropdownlist?

Comment: I would like to have TITLE for value and text also.

Comment: Then next step, @user560411, please click the "tick" symbol next to the vote count, to indicate your question is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your xml structure, this is hard

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<names><name>1</name><name>2</name></names>');
echo '<select>';
foreach ($xml as $obj)
{
  echo '<option value="',(string)$obj, '">', (string)$obj, '</option>', "\n";
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Hello, this imy XML structure.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CATEGORIES>
   
<CD id="1">
<TITLE>NEVER MIND THE BOLLOCKS</TITLE>
<BAND>SEX PISTOLS</BAND>
<YEAR>1977</YEAR>  
</CD>

<CD id="2">    
<TITLE>NEVERMIND</TITLE>
<BAND>NIRVANA</BAND>
<YEAR>1991</YEAR> 
</CD>
</CATEGORIES>